# Cross reference list of ids to index

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have grouped together a list of ids that are associated with a certain value and placed all these lists of ids into a dataframe. It looks like this: (with index = id)

```
    phase  list_ids
id  
a1  1      [a1,a2,c3] 
a2  3      [a1,b2,c3]  
b1  3      [a2,b2] 
b2  2      [b1,b2,c1] 
b3  3      [b2,c1] 
c1  1      [a1,a2,c3] 
c2  1      [a1,b1,c4] 
c3  2      [c1,c2,c4] 
c4  1      [c1,c2]
```

I want to iterate through these lists and cross reference them to the id index where phase equals either a 2 or 3, then just keep the ids that match within the original list (or if not possible, create a new column with modified lists). Something like this below:

```
    phase  list_ids
id  
a1  1      [a2,c3] #ids whose phase != 2|3 not kept in list
a2  3      [b2,c3]  
b1  3      [a2,b2] 
b2  2      [b1,b2] 
b3  3      [b2] 
c1  1      [a2,c3] 
c2  1      [b1] 
c3  2      [] 
c4  1      []
```

If possible I'd like to do this within the dataframe object as there are multiple features/dependencies for each row. Any tips on how to go about this?

My actual data:

```
               phase  ids
Study_id             
ACP-103-006    2.0   [ACP-103-006, ACP-103-020, ACP-103-019, ACP-10... 
ACP-103-008    2.0   [ACP-103-006, ACP-103-020, ACP-103-019, ACP-10...  
ACP-103-010    2.0   [ACP-103-042, ACP-103-034, ACP-103-014, ACP-10...  
ACP-103-012    3.0   [ACP-103-042, ACP-103-034, ACP-103-014, ACP-10...  
ACP-103-014    3.0   [ACP-103-042, ACP-103-034, ACP-103-014, ACP-10...
```

And the dtypes:

```
phase float64 
ids object
dtype: object
```

And the good_ids output:

```
print(good_ids)
{'CLS1001-301', 'EFC13799', 'AG120-C-009', 'IRBES_R_04320', 'LTS11298', 'CLS1003-302', '13621', 'TMC-ORI-10-01', '11935', 'C_8428', 'ACP-103-008', 'SFY13476', 'MNTX 301EXT', '14-OBE001-016', '812P310', 'V01-126A-201', 'VX06-770-101', 'EFC11603', ...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each element in the column `list_ids` is a list of strings, you could do the following:

First get a `set` of the "good" `ids` (where phase is 2 or 3):

```
good_ids = set(df[df["phase"].isin([2,3])].index)
print(good_ids)
#{'a2', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c3'}
```

Next use `apply` to filter the `list_ids` using `good_ids`:

```
df["list_ids"] = df["list_ids"].apply(lambda x: [val for val in x if val in good_ids])
print(df)
#    phase  list_ids
#id                 
#a1      1  [a2, c3]
#a2      3  [b2, c3]
#b1      3  [a2, b2]
#b2      2  [b1, b2]
#b3      3      [b2]
#c1      1  [a2, c3]
#c2      1      [b1]
#c3      2        []
#c4      1        []
```

Comment: Forgot to mention 'phase' column is of type 'float'. I get the error " 'float' object is not iterable".

Comment: That seems like a different error. Can you post the line where you are getting that error? My guess is that you may be missing the square brackets inside of `isin([...])`

Comment: ----> 1 sub["list_ids"] = sub["ids"].apply(lambda x: [val for val in x if val in good_ids])

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: Also, my original list in the dataframe is called ids, and I'm creating a new column called list_ids

Comment: I believe that error means the values in `sub["ids"]` are `float`, not lists of values as you showed in your question. If that is the case, you may need to do `sub["list_ids"] = sub["ids"].apply(lambda x: [val] if val in good_ids else [])` but it's hard to know for sure without seeing your actual data. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49885318/edit) your question and post the first few rows in your question using `sub.head(5)`?

Comment: Yea pretty stuck on this myself. Tried this last piece of code you suggested, got an AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'. So it's definitely a list... :(

Comment: Maybe the error is that somewhere in your `"ids"` column there is a `float` (and not a list). Try to do `sub.head(5)["ids"].apply(lambda x: [val for val in x if val in good_ids])` to see if the first 5 rows work.

Comment: Yea that seemed to work. I recall some id's not having any non-numeric characters. Just gotta figure out how to recursively change all the types of all the list elements to get this to work.

Comment: You can try to convert all the "ids" into a list if they are not lists: `subs["ids"].apply(lambda x: x ifisinstance(x, list) else [x])`